# Sqoop 1.99.7 job not running on Apache Hadoop 3.2.0

Tags: hadoop, sqoop2

I am facing an error with Sqoop 1.99.7 on Hadoop 3.2.0. Attached are the errors. Not sure if someone has faced this error before.
I am trying to load data into HDFS from postgres 10.
Please let me know, what am i missing here 
[Sqoop 1.99.7 error log from resource manager UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBPUr.png)

Thanks Pankaj

Comment: YARN LOGS -                                                                                                        
  2019-02-26 12:11:59,055 FATAL [CommitterEvent Processor #0] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.YarnUncaughtExceptionHandler: Thread Thread[CommitterEvent Processor #0,5,main] threw an Error.  Shutting down now...
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils

Comment: Paste error log as text, not as image please